# General definition of piecewise continuity

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Is there a general definition of piecewise continuity for functions between topological spaces ?

Of course one can intuitively says that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is piecewise continuous if for every compact $K$ of $X$, we can find a sort of finite "pseudo partition" $\{ O_1, ..., O_n \}$ of $K$ with open sets such that for every $O_i$, $f$ is continuous on $O_i$ and can be continuously extended on $\bar{O}_i$.

By "pseudo partition" I mean that elements of $\{ O_1, ..., O_n \}$ are pairwise disjoint, $\bigcup_i O_i \subset K$ and $V = K \setminus \bigcup_i O_i$ is negligible (has empty interior).

However this definition seems broken somehow. With $X=\mathbb{R}$, for any piecewise continuous $f$ and any compact $K$, the set $V$ is always a finite set of points so there are no additional constrains to add on it. But as soon as we consider $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, I feel like $V$ can potentially be "infinitely twisted" or "fractal-like" and I'm not sure a good extension of piecewise continuity should include this kind of ill-behaved situations.

Comment: I'd simply suggest that $f|_U$ should be continuous where $U$ is a dense open subset.

Comment: I doubt it would be a valid generalization. If you consider the set $S = \{ 2^k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{0\}$ then it seems its indicator function $1_S : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ which is dense and open. But this function is not piecewise continuous according to the usual definition on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The appropriate generalization would depend on the context, in my estimation. However here is an option, when $Y$ has an order structure: Suppose $K\subseteq X$ is compact and $Y=[-\infty,\infty]$. Then $f:K\to [-\infty,\infty]$ is pwc if it's semicontinuous and there is a finite cover of $K$ by closed subsets whose interiors are pairwise disjoint and on each interior $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Also related are the interval exchange transformations (these are essentially piecewise linear maps which also permute the pieces according to a predetermined permutation), and their generalizations to higher dimensions (rectangle/polygon/polyhedron exchange transformations).

Comment: The general pattern seems to be this: $f:X\to Y$ is pw good if for some finite cover (whose elements come from a predetermined class of manageable subsets) of $X$ $f$ is good on the good part of each cell of the cover and less good on the intersections and other less good parts of cells.